# How to group_by a data frame with a condition and add some variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to do a 'group_by' on a dataframe with a condition inside but something is missing...
Yet the solution seems simple.....
Any help will be welcome !

```
var1 <- "no"

result <- starwars %>% 
  if (var1=="yes") group_by(.,gender)
  else if (var1=="no") group_by(.,gender,skin_color)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution might be not the most beautiful one, but it does what you want

```
if (var1 == "yes") 
  result <- starwars %>% group_by(gender) 
if (var1 == "no")
  result <- starwars %>% group_by(gender, skin_color)
```

and after each `group_by` you specify the summary functions you want to apply, or whatever other operation you need

---

#### EDIT

Another possible solution after reading this [post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/conditional-pipelines/6076/2) is using **conditional pipelines**, i.e.

```
starwars %>% 
  {if (var1 == "yes") group_by(., gender) else .} %>% 
  {if (var1 == "no") group_by(., gender, skin_color) else .}
```

Since I don't have a sample data of yours I haven't tested it, but it should work

Comment: @DamienDotta Nice to hear that! Please consider accepting the answer if you found that useful